# NumPy 'as_strided' for strided sliding window over RGBA image (3D array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stride

I've done research and looked over several questions on SO to figure out the proper set-up of strides and shape, but it's been giving me problems.

I have an image array of shape `(250, 250, 4)` (example) and need to use `as_strided` to create a sliding window of size `(50, 50)` across all channels.

Assuming:

```py
x = np.random.random((250, 250, 4)) * 255
image = x.astype(np.uint8)
strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(image, shape=(?, ?, ?, ?, ?), strides=(?, ?, ?, ?, ?))
```

Meaning `strided[0, 0, 0]` would return the R channel of shape `(50,50)` equivalent to `image[0:50, 0:50, 0]`, and `strided[1, 1, 2]` would return the B channel equivalent to `image[50:100, 50:100, 2]`

I'm needing to use `as_strided` because I am given a memory view of a massive image (multiple GB in size), the above is just an example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The `sliding window` function was added as the safer and easier cover for `as_strided`.  Would it work for you?

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for the suggestion, I have already actually tried using that, and found that I am unable. The object I'm provided was an odd implementation of `__array__` which prevents me from using it. I'm unsure if `sliding_window_view` is implemented using `as_strided`, so I wanted to at least give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities with `sliding_window`:

```
In [9]: arr = np.ones((250,250,4),int)
In [10]: x = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr,(50,50),(0,1))
In [11]: x.shape
Out[11]: (201, 201, 4, 50, 50)
In [12]: x = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr,(50,50,4))
In [13]: x.shape
Out[13]: (201, 201, 1, 50, 50, 4)
```

In the first case, strides is: `(8000, 32, 8, 8000, 32)`

In the second,  `(8000, 32, 8, 8000, 32, 8)`

Comment: Unfortunately in my case I am unable to use `sliding_window_view` to figure out the strides and shape, since my actual image is massive and also a custom object that doesn't accept the usage of `sliding_window_view`. Also, I believe that the `dtype` of `arr` in your answer is `np.int32` which would not work with my example in the question that uses `np.uint8`, so the strides would be different here as well.